# Slider puzzle in python without pygame only functions

Tags: python

How to add the inputs I inserted here like the up move list, etc. so my puzzle will also move when you click the key you inserted for the input.

Also any ideas on how to add the automatic solver option for this code?

```
import random,sys

game_on = True
move = 0
up_move = []
down_move = []
left_move = []
right_move = []
eight_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
fifteen_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
up = input("Enter a key for up: ")
up_move.append(up)
down = input("Enter a key for down: ")
down_move.append(down)
left = input("Enter a key for left: ")
left_move.append(left)
right = input("Enter a key for right: ")
right_move.append(right)
n_o_t = int(input("Do you want to play 8 or 15 puzzle? "))

if n_o_t == 8:
    #------------------ to get shuffled list -----------
    random.shuffle(eight_list)
    print('\n'*2)
    #------------------ to make list of lists -----------
    matrix=[]
    while eight_list !=[]:
        matrix.append(eight_list[:3])
        eight_list = eight_list[3:]
    #------------------- function to find where the zero is ------
    def zero(board):
        global empty_space
        for x in range (len(board)):
            for y in range(len(board[x])):
                if board[x][y] == 0:
                    empty_space = (x,y)
        return empty_space
    #----------------------- function to draw the board -----------
    def draw_board(board):
        print('\n\t+-------+-------+-------|')
        for x in range (len(board)):
            for y in range(len(board[x])):
                if board[x][y] == 0:
                    print('\t|  XX' , end='')
                else:
                    print('\t|  ' + '{:02d}' .format(board[x][y]), end=' ') 
            print('\n\t+-------+-------+-------|')
    # ------------------------ function to ask for the number to move ---------- 
    def ask_number():
        global num , piece 
        num = input('\nplease type the number of the piece to move : ( q ) to quit  ')
        if num in ['q','Q']:
            print('\n\ngame over  ')
            sys.exit()     
        num = int(num)
        piece=()
        for i in range(len(matrix)):
            for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
                if num == matrix[i][j]:
                    piece = (i,j)
        return piece , num
    #---------------------------------------------- game starts here -------------
    zero(matrix)
    while game_on:
        draw_board(matrix)      
        ask_number()         
        if num > 8:
            print('illegal move , try again  ')
        else:
            if(empty_space==(piece[0]-1,piece[1]))\
            or(empty_space==(piece[0]+1,piece[1]))\
            or(empty_space==(piece[0],piece[1]-1))\
            or(empty_space==(piece[0],piece[1]+1)):
                matrix[empty_space[0]][empty_space[1]]=num
                matrix[piece[0]][piece[1]]=0
                empty_space=(piece[0],piece[1])
                move = move +1
                print()
                print('you have made ',move , 'moves so far ')
                print(2*'\n')
            else:
                print('illegal move , try again ')
elif n_o_t == 15:
    #------------------ to get shuffled list -----------
    random.shuffle(fifteen_list)
    print('\n'*2)
    #------------------ to make list of lists -----------
    matrix=[]
    while fifteen_list !=[]:
        matrix.append(fifteen_list[:4])
        fifteen_list = fifteen_list[4:]
    #------------------- function to find where the zero is ------
    def zero(board):
        global empty_space
        for x in range (len(board)):
            for y in range(len(board[x])):
                if board[x][y] == 0:
                    empty_space = (x,y)
        return empty_space
    #----------------------- function to draw the board -----------
    def draw_board(board):
        print('\n\t+-------+-------+-------+-------|')
        for x in range (len(board)):
            for y in range(len(board[x])):
                if board[x][y] == 0:
                    print('\t|  XX' , end='')
                else:
                    print('\t|  ' + '{:02d}' .format(board[x][y]), end=' ') 
            print('\n\t+-------+-------+-------+-------|')
    # ------------------------ function to ask for the number to move ---------- 
    def ask_number():
        global num , piece 
        num = input('\nplease type the number of the piece to move : ( q ) to quit  ')
        if num in ['q','Q']:
            print('\n\ngame over  ')
            sys.exit()     
        num = int(num)
        piece=()
        for i in range(len(matrix)):
            for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
                if num == matrix[i][j]:
                    piece = (i,j)
        return piece , num
    #---------------------------------------------- game starts here -------------
    zero(matrix)
    while game_on:
        draw_board(matrix)      
        ask_number()         
        if num > 15:
            print('illegal move , try again  ')
        else:
            if(empty_space==(piece[0]-1,piece[1]))\
            or(empty_space==(piece[0]+1,piece[1]))\
            or(empty_space==(piece[0],piece[1]-1))\
            or(empty_space==(piece[0],piece[1]+1)):
                matrix[empty_space[0]][empty_space[1]]=num
                matrix[piece[0]][piece[1]]=0
                empty_space=(piece[0],piece[1])
                move = move +1
                print()
                print('you have made ',move , 'moves so far ')
                print(2*'\n')
            else:
                print('illegal move , try again ')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module pynput can be used for this purpose

It has a keyboard module that can detect key presses. The only downside is that if you are trying to press down a printable character, it will type on the shell, IDLE, or whatever you are using. If you use something like the arrow keys however, nothing will appear. The cursor will just move.

Here is an example of pynput:

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print("pressed"+key.char)
    except AttributeError: #special character
        print("pressed", key)

def on_release(key):
    try:
        print("released "+key.char)
    except AttributeError: #special character
        print("released", key)

listener = keyboard.Listener(
    on_press=on_press,
    on_release=on_release)
listener.start()
```